# Try to perform a sort but the output does not appear to sort the output

Tags: groovy

I have a little issue with some sorting in my Groovy scrip and I am not sure why it is not working as expected.

Below is the JSON I am trying to sort:

```
{
   "aaa":    [
            {
         "aaa1": xxx,
         "aaa2": "xxx",
         "bbb": [         {
            "bbb1": xx,
            "bbb2":             [
               1,
               2
            ],
            "ccc": [],
            "ccc1": xxx
         }]
      },
           {
         "aaa1": xxx,
         "aaa2": "xxx",
         "bbb": [         {
            "bbb1": xx,
            "bbb2":             [
               1,
               2
            ],
            "ccc": [],
            "ccc1": xxx
         }]
      }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to sort this JSON by 'policyid' but it doesn't seem to sort it and I have no idea why it isn't as to me the code seems correct:

Below is what I want it to output:

```
[   {ccc=[1], bbb1=xxx, aaa1=[]}, 
    {ccc=[1, 2], bbb2=xxx, aaa2=[]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

```
log.info testsort.sort{a,b -> a.policyid <=> b.policyid}
```

You access `policyid` field while it should be `policyId`. Change mentioned line to:

```
log.info testsort.sort{a,b -> a.policyId <=> b.policyId}
```

and you will get the output:

```
[policyId:31, passengerSeqIds:[2], optionalPassengerSeqIds:[], cost:25]
[policyId:34, passengerSeqIds:[1], optionalPassengerSeqIds:[], cost:40]
[policyId:35, passengerSeqIds:[1, 2], optionalPassengerSeqIds:[], cost:72]
```

Comment: Oh my god, been stuck on this for almost an hour. How Silly